# MySQL loop for geospatial analysis

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, geospatial

My apologies if this is answered elsewhere; I looked and have tried several things, but am unable to solve this.

What I want to do: In MySQL, I have one table containing calls for service data from our police department, and another table containing vacant properties. Each table has latitude, longitude fields. We want to know for each call for service, was it within 100 feet of a vacant property? Here's the query we have written, using an example coordinate, to test if the distance analysis works:

```
SELECT
    address, (
        (20903520) 
    * acos (
        cos ( radians(38.67054) )
        * cos( radians( lat ) )
        * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-90.22942) )
        + sin ( radians(38.67054) )
        * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM vacants
HAVING distance < 100;
```

How can I write a loop to go through each call for service location and test it against each vacant location to see if for each call, was there a vacant property found within a 100-foot radius? I've tried writing a DECLARE statement, creating a COUNTER variable, and using the BEGIN/END syntax. 
None of them seemed to accomplish it, though perhaps I just wasn't writing them the correct way. SQL isn't my strongest; I much prefer Python, but we think doing this through a SQL query will be faster than looping through the .csv files. There are about 2.5 million call for service records. 
In the end, we want to be able to say "out of 2.5 million calls for service, X many were within 100 feet of a vacant property." 
I'd also like to be able to output a .csv file with the address of the vacant property, the distance of how far from the call for service the vacant found within the 100-foot radius is, and two other fields from the call for service table (original call code and final call code).

Something like this, but with two fields added. This comes from the test query I provided.

[image: Results of test query]

We also want to do the reverse analysis, to see how many calls for service were within a 100-foot radius of each property.

Here's example data - calls for service coordinates:

```
38.595767638008056,-90.2316138251402
38.57283495467307,-90.24649031378685
38.67497061776659,-90.28415976525395
38.67650431524285,-90.25623757427952
38.591971519414784,-90.27782710145746
38.61272746420862,-90.23292862245287
38.67312983860098,-90.23591869583113
38.625956494342674,-90.18853950906939
38.69044465638584,-90.24339061920696
38.67745024638241,-90.20657832034047`
```

Vacant property coordinates:

```
38.67054,-90.22942
38.642956,-90.21466
38.671535,-90.27293
38.666367,-90.23749
38.65339,-90.23141
38.645996,-90.20334
38.60214,-90.224815
38.67265,-90.214134
38.665504,-90.274414
38.668354,-90.269966`
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please post the structure of the tables that store "service data" and "vacant properties"

Comment: Sure, here are the CREATE TABLE statements I used:
`CREATE TABLE cfs (
event VARCHAR(25),
complaint VARCHAR(25),
start VARCHAR(50),
end VARCHAR(50),
og_code VARCHAR(50),
final_code VARCHAR(50),
disposition VARCHAR(50),
priority VARCHAR(20),
address VARCHAR(50),
district INT,
lat VARCHAR(50),
long VARCHAR(50)
);`

`CREATE TABLE vacants (
address VARCHAR(100),
lat VARCHAR(50),
long VARCHAR(50)
);`

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. In you example, is `38.67054` a longitude or a latitude ? and what is `20903520` ?

Comment: Latitude. `20903520` is miles converted to feet (3959 * 5280)

Answer (score 1):

Your sine/cosine calculations will be slow ad can't use a index. However MySQL has good support for geometries ad r-tree indexes for efficient access.

The way to store your places is by having them in a data type like `POINT` and using geometric functions like `st_distance` to calculate the distance.

Example based on your info:

```
CREATE TABLE vacants (address varchar(255), geo POINT NOT NULL SRID 4326,  SPATIAL KEY (geo))
insert into vacants VALUES ('123 some str', ST_PointFromText('POINT(8.6949639 50.1139589)', 4326) );
insert into vacants VALUES ('123 some ave', ST_PointFromText('POINT(8.6779835 50.1156941)', 4326) );
SELECT address, st_distance(geo, ST_PointFromText('POINT(8.532687 50.1036198)', 4326)) as `distance in meters` FROM vacants;
+--------------+---------------------+
| address      | distance in meters  |
+--------------+---------------------+
| 123 some str | 17983.567531177974  |
| 123 some ave | 16124.382142034325  |
+--------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

The SRID value of 4326 describes the spatial relation id and describes a geometric system like the earth. For other planets or artificial geometric structures you eed different values.
The geometries I describe as WKT or "well known text" which is a standardized form to describe all sorts of geometric objects. The data can be provided n other formats as well (i.e. geojson or some others)
The locations I picked are somewhere in central Germany.

With that distance you should be able to create the reverse search quite easily.

For all details refer to the manual pages at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html